Failed to query latest Homebrew/brew Git tag
I tried everything and it's still showing this error 'Failed to query latest Homebrew/brew Git tag.' while trying to install homebrew. Has anybody had this isssue and solved it?
I could not find much answers for this error anywhere.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

After much effort, I found the solution here.
If there is a line related to XAMPP in your .bash_profile or .zprofile file, the problem may be caused by this.
After I removed these lines, the homebrew installation was completed successfully. After installing Homebrew, I added it again.
My .zprofile file:
#HOMEBREW
eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
#NODE
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/homebrew/Cellar/node@20/20.15.0/bin 
#FLUTTER
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/username/FlutterSetup/flutter/bin"
export PATH="$PATH":"$HOME/.pub-cache/bin"
#PHP
export XAMPP_HOME=/Applications/XAMPP <--- 
export PATH=${XAMPP_HOME}/bin:${PATH} <--- 
export PATH                           <--- Remove this lines


It worked! for me terminal file was.zshrc Thanks.
